# jQuery how to use event driven variable in multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that assigns values to multiple dynamically rendered input boxes based on their events. One of these values originate from a Modal, I would like to assign the value from the Modal to a textbox but am having trouble getting the value inside the Modal saving function as the value is generated in an external function. i have tried nesting or separating the two functions but I can't get it right. I would really appreciate any help.

**Here is the code for the dynamic inputs in a table**

```
<table id="requested-wh-stock-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="50%">Luminaire</th>
                            <th>Shelve Number</th>
                            <th>Order Quantity</th>
                            <th>Delivered Qty</th>
                            <th>Back Order Qty</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($salesorder as $request)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" class="wh_id" name="wh_id" value="{{$request->wh_id}}">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="wh_id" name="light_id" value="{{$request->light_id}}">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="luminaire" value="{{$request->luminaire}}" readonly></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control shelve_number" name="shelve_number" id="shelve_number" value="" onfocus="popModal(this)"></td>
                                <td><input type="number" class="form-control order_quantity" name="order_quantity" id="order_quantity" value="{{$request->quantity}}" readonly/></td>
                                <td><input type="number" class="form-control delivered_quantity" name="delivered_quantity" id="delivered_quantity" value=""/></td>
                                <td><input type="number" class="form-control backorder_quantity" name="backorder_quantity" id="backorder_quantity" value="" readonly/></td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**Here is the Modal Code**

```
<!--Shelve Modal-->
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select Shelve Number</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:5%;margin-right:10%">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label>Shelve Number</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select id="shelve_no" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="shelve_no">
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="save_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        /div>
    </div>
  <!--End of Model-->
```

**Here are my 2 functions**

```
function popModal(x){
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }

        //Return list of Shelves based on ordered luminaire
        $('.shelve_number').on('focus',function(){  
            var wh_id = 1; 
            var light_id = 9963;
            var elementChanges = "<option value='0' disabled selected>Select Shelve Number</option>";
            document.getElementById('shelve_no').innerHTML = elementChanges;
            $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url: '{!! url('warehouse/getshelveByluminaire') !!}/'+wh_id+"/"+light_id, 
            }).done(function(res) {
                  console.log(res);
                  var elems ="<option value='0' disabled  selected='selected'>Choose Shelve</option>";
                  for(var x=0;x<res.length;x++){
                    elems =elems + "<option value='"+JSON.stringify(res[x])+"'>"+res[x].shelve_no+"</option>";
                  }
                  document.getElementById('shelve_no').innerHTML = elems;
            });
        });

         //Assign Shelve number
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.shelve_number').on('change',function() {
                let parent = $(this).parents('tr');
                let shelve = parent.find('.shelve_number');
                var selected_shelve = jQuery("#shelve_no option:selected").val();
                var shelve_selected =JSON.parse(selected_shelve).shelve_no;


           //Save Modal function
             $('#save_modal').on('click',function(x){
                    shelve.val(shelve_selected);
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                });
            });




           });
```

The shelve listing function is working fine, as the shelves get listed in a drop down and I can select a shelve, but the moment I click on "Save Changes" nothing happens, and there is nothing in the Console. Please assist, I am having trouble with the last 2 functions [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rRaF.png)

Comment: The `#save_modal` event listener never gets attached because the value of the `.shelve_number` inputs never change.

Comment: @Zera What event should I attach to the ``.shelve_number`` input, I have tried ``onfocus`` event but I figured the time the ``.shelve_number`` input gets focus the shelve value has not been set/selected yet

Comment: Why not move the one event listener out of the other event listener?

Comment: I have tried taking out the ``$('#save_modal').on('click'`` event but the problem is that I need the ``shelve`` variable which gets assigned inside the other event listener and I can't figure out a way to access it outside the ``$('.shelve_number').on('change'`` hence I was trying to nest the two listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the variables global using `window`.

```
function popModal(x){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}

$('.shelve_number').on('focus', function() {
    let parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    window.shelve = parent.find('.shelve_number');
    var wh_id = 1; 
    var light_id = 9963;
    var elementChanges = "<option value='0' disabled selected>Select Shelve Number</option>";
    $('#shelve_no').html(elementChanges);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{!! url('warehouse/getshelveByluminaire') !!}/" + wh_id + "/" + light_id
    }).done(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        var elems = "<option value='0' disabled  selected='selected'>Choose Shelve</option>";
        for (var x = 0; x < res.length; x++) {
            elems = elems + "<option value='" + JSON.stringify(res[x]) + "'>" + res[x].shelve_no + "</option>";
        }
        $('#shelve_no').html(elems);
    });
});

//Assign Shelve number
$(document).ready(function() {
      //Save Modal function
      $('#save_modal').on('click',function(x) {
          var selected_shelve = jQuery("#shelve_no option:selected").val();
          var shelve_selected = JSON.parse(selected_shelve).shelve_no;
          shelve.val(shelve_selected);
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      });
});
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but for some reason the `shelve` variable is not being detected as a global variable

Comment: I have modified it.